# Google Analytics - Set the USER_ID from a session variable

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to set USER_ID in Google Analytics to be a value of a session variable. Is that even possible? If not I could use a hidden variable on the page. I went to webpage https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id but it didn't have an example for how to set the USER_ID from a session variable and the only example it did have uses PHP and I'm running from a box (IIS 7.5) which PHP is not set up on.

Currently I have the following code in script tags at the bottom of the ASPX page:

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-59964433-1', 'auto'); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('set', '&uid', {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

I would like to change *{{USER_ID}}* to a session variable or a hidden variable on the page (maybe use `getElementById`). If anyone has an example of either using a session variable or a hidden variable on the page, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

There's an example on the page you linked to in your question:

```
<?php
// New Google Analytics code to set User ID.
// $userId is a unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable string ID.
if (isset($userId)) {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': '%s' });";
  echo sprintf($gacode, $userId);
} else {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');";
  echo sprintf($gacode);
}?>
```

Comment: Yes but that example is in PHP. I can't use that. -- John

Comment: Then you should have specified that in your original post. If you want an answer to your question, you have to give people the information they need to help you. FWIW, the concepts in the PHP example should be transferable to pretty much any language.

Comment: In my original post I did mention I can't use PHP. Also I agree the "concept" in the PHP example should be transferrable but getting the actual code to implement the "concept" is, I'm sure you'd agree,  often another issue in its own self.

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer:

I added a hidden variable to the master page called "hidUserColleagueID"

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidUserColleagueID" runat="server" Value="UnknownUser" />
```

In the code behind of the master page, If a user logs in then I set the "hidUserColleageID" to the name of logged in user which is contained in a session variable (I'm using VB)

```
hidUserColleagueID.Value = Session("USERNAME")
```

At the bottom of the master page I added the google analytics code. The var USER_ID is set to the value of the hidUserColleagueID field. If it equals "UnknownUser" then sends information to google analytics without passing who is logged in. If the hidUserColleagueID field does not equal "UnknownUser" it sends information to google analytics with who is logged in.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

var USER_ID = document.getElementById('<%=hidUserColleagueID.ClientID%>').value;
if (USER_ID == "UnknownUser") 
      ga('create', 'UA-99998765-1', 'auto'); // don't set the user id as it is unknown
  else
      ga('create', 'UA-99998765-1', { 'userId': USER_ID });  // set the userID = USER_ID which is the username of the logged in user
</script>
```

John